# Messages 8.0 not showing video icon

Tags: macos, messages

On brand new Mac running Yosemite, Messages (Version 8.0) not showing video icon at all. No "Video" tab in menu options at the top either.

Comment: is it not under messages pref ?

Answer (score 1):

As Michael points out, if you enable the Bonjour account, the Video Preferences Tab will appear.

Apparently Messages doesn't recognize iCloud accounts as AIM equivalents. No AIM or gChat accounts or their equivalents, no Video Preferences tab and no Buddy Lists.

Answer (score 0):

Afaik, there shouldn't be. And no Apple documentation I have Googled states it is should be there.

Yet at least when going to Google Talk buddy list there is Audio/Video Button which can be pressed and you presented with hidden tab in Preferences

[image: Really strange]

UPDATE: Now what I have found is that if you press <kbd>Optn</kbd> when going to Preferences of Messages you will got this (disregard that I don't have camera)

[image]

Comment: Actually that is not correct. There is a Audio/Video in Messages.

Comment: Now you are right. There is option for audio/video though there is no Audio/Video tab in Preferences. Yet you can check preferences that opens in nonexistent tab after you Press preferences button in Video Window which is up after pressing on Green icon in Buddies Window. Strange

Comment: Well that might be true for Yosemite, but it is still there on Mavericks

Comment: It is sure there in Mavericks but it is halfway there in Yosemite

Comment: I just activated it in Preferences and looking at my ugly face :) on 10.9.5 but I newer use messages anyway.

Comment: I have added screenshot to the answer. Really strange

Comment: what happened to your camera?

Comment: Firewire is not working and I have Firewire iSight

Answer (score 0):

I just got the Audio/Video tab to appear by enabling Bonjour instant messaging.